# How to get google static map images with QT (C++)

Tags: c++, qt, google-maps, network-programming

I am trying to use QT to implement an application which download google static map images and show the map on a GUI application. In this way the local saved images can be used when there is no internet access.

I have checked a lot of example using QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkRequest, QNetworkReply, but it will give back some information like "SSL handshake failed" and I am not able to download the image.

The url to download images is:

```
    urlbase = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=%f,%f&zoom=%d&maptype=%s&size=%dx%d&format=jpg"
```

Previous I used Python to do the work:

```
    result = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    tile = PIL.Image.open(cStringIO.StringIO(result))
```

which was very easy and convenient.

But when comes to QT and C++, it seems like all need a lot of self-built functions. So is there any easy way to do the job with C++ and QT?

Comment: The best I can tell you is: it all works for me. Please show a complete example of how you download an image, and what Qt binary do you use (if self-build, provide complete `configure` line). Perhaps use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31619378/1329652) as a starting point: it builds and runs and also downloads over `https://` if you just modify the url.

Comment: The answer doesn't work for my case. It gives error message: "SSL handshake failed".

Comment: It seems like most of the methods work with "http://" but not with "https://". So the problem must come from "https://". I think I know why.

Comment: Again: where did you get your copy of Qt from? Whatever copy you're using doesn't include OpenSSL, and that's why things don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement your gui with [QML module](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-index.html) and use [Map QML type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-map.html) for map.

It supports caching for "offline" features:

> For "online" Map plugins, network bandwidth and latency can be major
>   contributors to the user's perception of performance. Extensive
>   caching is performed to mitigate this, but such mitigation is not
>   always perfect. For "offline" plugins, the time spent retrieving the
>   stored geographic data and rendering the basic map features can often
>   play a dominant role. Some offline plugins may use hardware
>   acceleration themselves to (partially) avert this.

Example of map in qml:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is there any compelling reason to use Qt network functionality? You can just stick the PIL image into a [QGraphicsPixmapItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.8/qgraphicspixmapitem.html), and place that into a [QGraphicsScene](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.8/qgraphicsscene.html), which will get you the interactivity you want out of Qt.

Comment: No, but I wish to use Qt to write the program. My question is actually about requesting data from url, not about loading image to GUI. Previously I used Python to write the whole GUI, but the whole program is too large and crashes sometimes. So I wish to use C++ (Qt) so that the program can be more stable. This is why I changed to Qt.

Comment: Ah, I thought you intended to use PyQt. PyQt is pretty darn stable relative to C++ Qt, should you choose to go that route.

Comment: Oh, really? I was using wxPython; it crashes when too many widgets and elements. Maybe I can try PyQt.